# php: how do I load a jpg from the user desktop to the server using php?

Tags: php

How do I enable a user to be able to select a file from the desktop and load it to a server using php?

thanks

Comment: Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: http://www.reconn.us/content/view/30/51/ here is a good article for you.

Comment: For people voting to close this as "not a real question", what's wrong with it?  Seems like a simple question with a solid answer.

Comment: @MerlynThere are a couple dozen copies of this question here already; we're just too lazy to pick one to mark this a duplicate of. That's why the downvote button says "shows no research effort or not useful". If you can answer the question with the most basic of searching and reading, it's not a *problem* that needs an answer. It's a waste of time and space to repeat the same thing the manual says a 1000th time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php image upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655657/php-image-upload)

Comment: @Dan: I had to search 3 pages to find that one that it was actually a dupe of, rather than a near-dupe. I guess I'll take this advice for future questions, as we can't edit or undo these votes

Comment: @Merlyn *None* of them really belong here anyway, it's a "how do I print Hello World" type thing. You go to the manual, not a Q&A site. I know, it's a mean world...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First put this in a file called `upload.php`:

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

And then put this in a file called `upload-file.html`:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Make sure these 2 files are in the same directory.

And lastly, create another directory called "uploads" in the same one as the 2 files above.

If you want more information, here is the [tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php).

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for not just linking the docs, but extracting the relevant info.  You may want to link to the article, too (if you didn't get this from the php.net manual article, then just check other people's answers/comments to find the link).

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: I added the link to it. Thanks for the upvote :)